# Should I resign if I sense that I could get fired/laid off in next review?

Tags: job-change, termination

I am not performing according to the standards of my current organization and I can feel it. In the latest review it was mentioned in a different way. I am trying my best but now losing confidence in my capabilities. Perhaps I am not good enough for this place. Should I wait for the next review or start looking for another job and quit here. I have 3 months until next review cycle.

Comment: What are your qualifications and what are you experienced in and what the have offered you, I mean workwise? Can you add some details?

Comment: Welcome to the site anu. As written your question is on the border of being off-topic since you're asking for advice specific to your situation. My answer is intended to be generic so consider generalising your question somewhat, like "How should I proceed when I sense that I could fired/laid off?" instead of a black-and-white "Should I resign?".

Comment: @Lilienthal It was my first question here, I will surely keep this in mind in future. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If this is the United States, you do not get unemployment benefits if you resign on your own. But you do get unemployment benefits if you are fired or laid off, unless it was for misconduct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking a few separate questions. I'll answer them with generically applicable advice but note that we don't have the full picture of your situation and you do. As a general caveat: **strangers on the internet can't make up your mind for you, we can only help guide your decision making process.**

> Should I **resign** if I sense that I could get fired/laid off in next review?

**Probably not**, unless you are 100% certain that it's coming and feel that the ability to technically answer "No" to the question "Have you ever been fired?" is worth the loss of benefits and pay. Also factor in that you may be underestimating your performance and may be imaging a worst-case scenario. Reasonable managers won't outright fire you but will give constant feedback, especially if your performance is putting your job at risk. You'd need to look at how former employees have been treated to figure out if your company handles resigning and firing well and let that factor into your thinking.

Keep in mind that it is much, **much** easier for people who are currently employed to find a new job. Even then, a job search could take months, sometimes years so you almost never want to resign like this.

> Should I wait for the next review or **start looking for another job** and quit here.

This is a different question though and with the limited insight you gave us into your situation I would say that **yes, you should start looking for another position.** You've experienced yourself that you're not performing up to the standards of your workplace and some issues were apparently already raised in a previous review (though see my next paragraph on that). I'm going to assume that you feel like you can perform better but for some reason this job isn't working out well for you. In that case (and provided you've been in this job for at least a year, maybe two) it makes sense to look into changing jobs since it's much better to try to find work that you can excel at and are motivated for.

**However, make sure that your performance really is substandard.** You wouldn't be the first person to underestimate his performance which can affect new entrants to the workforce especially. You mention getting a negative impression from your previous review but make sure you see you don't confuse constructive criticism, goals or minor things to improve on for real complaints about your performance. I despise people who bring up the [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) at every opportunity but I'll mention it before it's brought up in the comments. If you have a good relationship with your manager or get the impression that he's a reasonable person then you should ask to move your review up or just **have an informal meeting to discuss your performance and goals** outside their formal review process.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am working in an organization which is dream company of many final year IT students in my country and I surely dont want to lose the opportunity I have got here to learn and develop my skills. I spoke to my manager this week about how am I doing and based on his remarks I feel I should keep my negative feelings aside and give my best. I know I do have necessary skills to get any other job if required in short time. Thanks for the detailed advice.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should *always* be looking for another job, regardless of performance.

There are multiple factors constantly at play in hiring and firing decisions beyond your control - the economy, change of leadership/direction for the company, change of management in the department, budget cuts, preparation for cuts, etc.

Your performance can be great one year, but you can be downgraded the next due to company policy where someone must always be made the scapegoat. Nothing you can do. So, don't be too hard on yourself. Instead, make it a habit to track other jobs and update your resume.

Answer (score 1):

Without reading your entire review, we could only go off your word. Chances are it may have been positive criticism and you're taking it too personally. It's very doubtful that someone would attack you unprovoked and give you no room to improve. I would first not quit based on a single review. I would follow Lilienthal advice on waiting for the next review or ask your manager if you could sit down and discuss your last review and how you could improve. That would look a lot better and it would also allow you to gauge on if any of your fears are true or if you can improve. Whatever you do, do not tell them that you're looking for a new position or anything.

Depending on what your negative points are, it could follow you to the next job where they may not be as forgiving. What you have to establish before you quit is if the reviews are something you can improve upon and if it is something reasonable. For example if the review states you never deliver on time, but you feel that the deadline is unreasonable or you feel that you put in extra work to improve the product then explain why you feel that way.